# OOP PHP. Syntax Undefined property

Tags: php

I have an error probably because of the syntax  and I cant find how to do it correctly.

This is my code

```
function myFunction($id = 'ID')
{
    if (!$this->$id) {
        // TO DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

I have the next error

> Notice: Undefined property: Base::$ID ..... on line 278

I tried with

```
if (!$this->{$id}) {
```

but nothing

anyone know the correct syntax is. I cant find it on google neither.

Comment: Pretty sure you just mean `if(!$id)`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol no, i think he/she wants to check if property does exist. when you want to check whether property exists, don't access it, you can use `isset` or better use `property_exists` rather than direct access the property you doubt it exists or not. if the property does not exists, the script will throw an error. check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [property_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) instead of using direct access `if(!$this->$id)`:

```
function myFunction($id = 'ID')
{
    if (!property_exists($this, $id)) {
        // TO DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The function property_exists() is the solution. It is a shame that i cant do it  using my way.

Thanks Alfa

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining a property on your class, you should access it like such:

```
$this->id
```

not

```
$this->$id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
if(!$this->id) {
```

or

```
if(!$id) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an example how your code might work, and I kept the idea of accessing a property by a string. The first step is to have the class actually have a field named "ID". I set this field value in the constructor.

```
class My {
    private $ID;

    public function __construct($id) {
        $this->ID = $id;
    }

    public function myFunction($id='ID'){

       if(!property_exists($this, $id)){
         echo "$id not found";
       } else {
         echo $this->$id;  
       }

    }
}

$my = new My(4);
$my->myFunction();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this method to get the output.

```
$this->id
```

or

```
$id
```